# I could not understand the meaning of the last paragraph in the the text below

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, c++11

The section below can be found on [this article](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/c++mm/threadsintro.html#loss) by Hans Boehm (BTW a very good article, as far as I could read it):

> **The problem with pure sequential consistency**
>
> Unfortunately, it is too expensive to guarantee sequentially
>   consistent executions in all cases. For example, reconsider the
>   program above. Most processors do not actually wait for the initial
>   assignments to complete before executing the second statements in each
>   thread. The initial assignments just cause the value 1 to be saved in
>   a store buffer, where it waits to be copied to memory, but is not yet
>   visible to another processor. If the two threads were to execute in
>   lock step on different processors, it is quite likely that both r1 and
>   r2 will be zero, because the reads of both x and y occur before the
>   writes become visible to the other thread.
>
> Similarly, compilers routinely transform code in ways that violate
>   sequential consistency. For example, if our initial example occurred
>   as part of a larger program, the compiler might decide to move one or
>   both of the r2 = x and r1 = y "load" operations to the beginning of
>   their respective threads, to give them more time to complete before
>   the values in r1 and r2 are needed. Causing the load to happen early
>   is essentially equivalent to the hardware delaying the store; it can
>   again cause both loads to read zero. Since the two operations in each
>   thread touch independent variables, there is no reason for the
>   compiler to believe that they are not interchangeable. This kind of
>   compiler transformation can produce significant performance
>   improvements, and we do not want to disallow it.
>
> In essence, both hardware and compilers may perform very similar
>   optimizations that reorder memory references as perceived by other
>   threads.
>
> There has been a significant amount of research on reducing the cost
>   of sequential consistency, both in hardware, and through more complete
>   compiler analysis. But most experts feel that the hardware costs are
>   still too high, and the compiler optimizations require too much
>   information about the entire program to be generally feasible. And, as
>   we will see below, insisting on pure sequential consistency generally
>   does not provide us with any real advantage.

After a few trials I was able to understand the article up to, but not including this last paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, we are trying to do it, but it costs a-alot and doesn't really get us anything.

Comment: Could you elaborate what is unclear to you about the last paragraph? I think it says "hardware designed to be sequentially consistent would be too slow or too expensive, compilers required to always produce sequentially consistent code would require too complex analysis".

Comment: @dyp For example: `compilers required to always produce sequentially consistent code would require too complex analysis`. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Allowing *safe* optimizations, i.e. optimizations that don't break sequentially consistent execution under the as-if rule, would require too hard analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"pure sequential consistency" is equivalent to declaring every single variable in a C++ program to be `std::atomic`. The compiler and processor are completely locked down in terms of reordering: they simply may not reorder memory accesses at all. Multithreaded programs would have very nice predictable semantics, and be slower than molasses. The "cost" referred to in the first sentence is the loss of performance necessitated by the requirements of pure sequential consistency. Research into finding ways to reduce that cost - either in hardware or by making compilers smarter to find more optimization opportunities that do not violate pure sequential consistency - has not been fruitful.

The last sentence "And, as we will see below, insisting on pure sequential consistency generally does not provide us with any real advantage." suggests that relaxing the memory ordering constraints from pure sequential consistency can greatly increase performance, hopefully without rendering the memory semantics incomprehensible.